# How to setup a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a completely beginner question about the setup of artificial neural networks.  Basically it boils down to:

- How do I put in data and get results?  For example, classification: let say I have 10 input features, all numerical, and 5 output classes.
- How do I set up my input layer and my output layer?  Would it be good to have 10 input nodes, one for each feature and feed each node a single numerical value during feed forward evaluation?
- How about the output layer?  Should I set up 1 node, 5 nodes?
- What is the classification rule for neural networks?

Comment: I think you will have more luck with this question on the [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange, the statistics SE site. There are already quite a few NN questions, and a [neural-net tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my mind, or the rest of knowlegd about back-propagation neural networks, I would start with two layers with 10 perceptron in the first and 5 in the last using a the sigmoid logistic activation function.

$$ 1/(1+exp(-\beta x)) $$

Entering dimension 10, output dimension 5.

Better take a look at [Haykin, S. (1999). Neural Networks: A comprehensive foundation (2nd ed). Prentice Hall International.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132733501)

Chapter 4 Multlayer Perceptrons. If back-propagation NN most commom feed forward NN.

Also if you did not take a look, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)

If you give more details about your problem we might be able to give a better asnwer.

What you mean by classification rule?